# How to reference a plot that is displayed later with bookdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown, bookdown

[This section](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/fig-chunk.html) of the R Markdown Cookbook shows how to create a plot and to display it later in the document:

````
---
output: bookdown::pdf_document2
---

We generate a plot in this code chunk but do not show it:

```{r cars-plot, dev='png', fig.show='hide'}
plot(cars)
```

After another paragraph, we introduce the plot:

![A nice plot.](`r knitr::fig_chunk('cars-plot', 'png')`)
````

The problem I have is that I can't reference this plot in the text. See the following code and output:

````
---
output: bookdown::pdf_document2
---

We generate a plot in this code chunk but do not show it:

```{r cars-plot, dev='png', fig.show='hide'}
plot(cars)
```

Here's a reference to this plot: figure \@ref(fig:cars-plot).

After another paragraph, we introduce the plot:

![A nice plot.](`r knitr::fig_chunk('cars-plot', 'png')`)
````

[image]

Note that if I display the plot immediately, the reference works well:

````
---
output: bookdown::pdf_document2
---

We generate a plot in this code chunk but do not show it:

```{r cars-plot, fig.cap="A nice plot."}
plot(cars)
```

Here's a reference to this plot: figure \@ref(fig:cars-plot).
````

[image]

How can display the plot later but still be able to reference it? I know that I could simply move the chunk where I want the plot to appear but this is not ideal in my case.

Comment: What about replacing `\@ref(fig:cars-plot)` with `[1](#fig:cars-plot)`, i.e. `[link text](#ID)`? More information [here](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/cross-references.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ref.label` in a later chunk and refer to the later chunk name in the figure reference.

````
---
output: bookdown::pdf_document2
---

We generate a plot in this code chunk but do not show it:

```{r cars-plot, dev='png', fig.show='hide'}
plot(cars)
```

Here's a reference to this plot: figure \@ref(fig:cars-plot-show).

After another paragraph, we introduce the plot:

```{r cars-plot-show, ref.label="cars-plot", fig.cap="A Nice Plot"}

```
````